# Is Angular Material 2 available for JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material2

I read about the new stuff in Angular Material 2. Finally are predefined data table and pagination. But I'm a bit confused. On Github and the official site of material 2 are examples described in TypeScript only. Does that means, material 2 isn't available in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is available and npm package already has javascript bundles. You just need to install it using npm

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

and now you can use it in you angular javascript application.

Comment: Yes but this is the Material Version 1 not the new one you know? Pozdrav :)

Comment: @yuro It's the latest version (i.e. Angular Material 2)!